# Add geometry options in class result an "Unused global option(s)" warning

Tags: geometry, class-options

This small example cause a warning  `Unused global option(s):[showframe]` although the option is passed to `geometry` package

```
\documentclass[showframe]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document} 

text

\end{document}
```

Same example do not produce warnings with `graphicx` package

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document} 

\includegraphics[width=5cm]{image}

\end{document}
```

Comment: sent a feature request to the geometry maintainer, that it should correctly update the unused option list.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer do you want write access to the repo? :-)